# Ubuntu upgrade to 18.04 LTS from 17.10 failed

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to 18.04 LTS from 17.10 and after the completion of the upgrade it said upgrade failed you system will be unstable, recovery will run now. The system could not launch when I restarted the system first time and second time it started. However I see some software are not working and I submitting bug reports. Can I downgrade to 17.10 now? What if my system becomes unstable? should I then run in recover mode (Kernel 4.13)?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Ubuntu and re-instaling it?

Comment: Well I did not. Ubuntu is running in my laptop and uninstalling and installing means a lot (I need to reconfigure many a thing).

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem when upgrading to 16.04 on one of my computers.  I initially had booting problems, but it finally booted.  I got the same unstable error messages you describe.  I run a series of these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

I paid attention to the screen output of commands and ran the suggested command for that error.

Initially `cat /etc/lsb-release` showed the previous version.

It became stable by running the above commands 3 times.  `cat /etc/lsb-release` showed the intended `16.04`.  That was two years ago.  It's still running perfectly without any problems.

I believe trying to downgrade would be more problematic than fixing the upgrade issues.

All the commands was running from the console without GUI until the errors were addressed.

If the above commands (because of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` repository configuration) bring stability to 17.10, you should be able to complete your release upgrade to `18.04`.

Comment: +1 weird cat has to be run 3 times in a row!

Comment: There's some type of typo.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Ii was reading from cell phone in bright sunlight!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The 3 times part, I often do.  Sometimes an upgrade brings in new repository servers of which and update refreshes the caches, then the upgrade updates the apps and libraries from the new cache updates.  `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` sometimes shows more applications after running the three commands the first time.  This is especially the case when the system is broken.