# My upgrade crashed partway. What should I do?

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 17.04

Here are the details. I upgraded using the Software Update application from 17.04 to 17.10 and just before the upgrade got to the stage of "Cleaning System" (which comes after "Updating Packages" (paraphrased) and before "Rebooting computer" (paraphrased).

When I boot up my computer it says it is 17.10. Is there anything I should be aware of or make sure of given that the process didn't go perfectly?

Comment: Folow the steps provided in this answer: [Ubuntu upgrade to 18.04 LTS from 17.10 failed](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028939/29012)

Comment: @dsstorefile1I can't re-run the updater from 17.04 to 17.10 since my system is already 17.10 now.

Comment: @L.D.James the sequence of commands never threw me an error so the system must be fine, for the most part. thanks.

Comment: That sounds great!  I reread your question and see that you succeeded with your Upgrade, which the `cat /lsb-release`  and your bootup version notice is showing.  I had a few crashes, with recent release upgrades recently and in the past.  Most of the time, the crashes seem to have appeared after it had finished, and the upgrade was successful.  The other times, the commands in the link fixed any glitches.